# py2exe with Numpy/Scipy and Matplotlib DLL load fail

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, py2exe

I have a script that generates some plots that I would like to run generate an executable for so some friends who can't deal with CLI can use it. However the problem is that py2exe will compile simple scripts such as `print 'hello world'`, but when trying to include `matplotlib` and `numpy` I have issues.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import inspect
import itertools
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Those are all of the modules that the script requires and here is the py2exe error:

```
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 299, in _run
    py_files, extensions, builtins = self.parse_mf_results(mf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1095, in parse_
mf_results
    import Tkinter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Which was generated after calling `python setup.py py2exe` with the file `setup.py` defined as:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
from glob import glob
data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Python27\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*'))]
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    console = ['sequence-entropy.py']
  )
```

I've put the VC redist stuff in my the directory listed in `setup.py`.
The script runs and generates plots when run by CLI on my windows machine (not just the system it was written on). I've included the VC stuff, I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the same issue as here. [Errors with Matplotlib when making an executable with Py2exe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228774/errors-with-matplotlib-when-making-an-executable-with-py2exe-python)

I will just repeat the answer in the other question here.

You will need to copy the mpl-data folder too. Check this official wiki site http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

```
import matplotlib
...
setup(
    ...
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
)
```

You will need something like this in your setup.py for py2exe. 
hope it helps.