# Errors with Matplotlib when making an executable with Py2exe (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, executable, py2exe

I have a problem when trying to make an executable with a Python application.

For doing this, I'm using Py2exe with the 2.7 version of Python.

My application have 3 python scripts
  -> IHM_monotone_flux_GTC.py which is the one who launch a graphical interface

and then 2 others scripts:
  -> lectureDonnees.py
  -> main.py

In order to create an executable I made a setup.py file which is surely incomplete:

from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

setup(windows=['IHM_monotone_flux_gtc.py'])

Unfortunetaly, it doesn't work and I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "IHM_monotone_flux_gtc.py", line 16, in <module>
     File "main.pyc", line 22, in <module>
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 838, in <module>
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 749, in rc_params
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 664, in matplotlib_fname
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 292, in wrapper
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 585, in _get_data_path_cached
     File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 581, in _get_data_path
   RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files
```

Thanks for any help. (I'm working with Windows XP)

Cédric.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to copy the mpl-data folder too. Check this official wiki site http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

```
import matplotlib
...
setup(
    ...
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
)
```

You will need something like this in your setup.py for py2exe. 
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from Matplotlib 3.3.0 the function get_py2exe_datafiles() doesn't exist anymore: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.3.0.html

To know what to do, please look at: https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/71 and https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/169

SUMMARY:

I currently have matplotlib 3.6.0, wxpython 4.2.0, py2exe 0.13.0.0:

2 cases:

A - test.py with matplotlib only:

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows = ["test.py"]
)
```

should work

B - test.py with matplotlib and wxpython:

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows = ["test.py"]
)
```

should work BUT the need is ALSO to check stuff in py2exe/hooks.py as described in https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/169

```
def hook_matplotlib(finder, module):
    """matplotlib requires data files in a 'mpl-data' subdirectory in
    the same directory as the executable.
    """
    import ast
    from pkg_resources._vendor.packaging import version as pkgversion

    import matplotlib

    mpl_data_path = matplotlib.get_data_path()
    finder.add_datadirectory("mpl-data", mpl_data_path, recursive=True)

    # --- COMMENT BELOW LINE NOT TO EXCLUDE WXPYTHON ---------------------
    ##finder.excludes.append("wx")
    ## XXX matplotlib requires tkinter which modulefinder does not
    ## detect because of the six bug.
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    ...
```