# py2exe couldn't find the following matplotlib data files

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

As the title says, I'm trying to create an .exe file from a .py file using py2exe. When I do the conversion everything is ok (at least I have no emerging messages of problems) but when I execute the .exe file I get the following error:

[image]

I'm not really sure about how to solve this problem, if someone could help me I would really appreciate it. If my question isn't clear enough and you need more data about it, please don't hesitate to ask for it.

Y

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors with Matplotlib when making an executable with Py2exe (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228774/errors-with-matplotlib-when-making-an-executable-with-py2exe-python)